# Counting 3 columns with yes and no values together in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

The table has columns English, Spanish and French. Each with yes or no values and i want to count the number of yes and no for each column into one table.

I tried using distinct count but it cannot put all columns under one table.

It should appear like this:

```
Key| French   | Spanish |English|
--—| -------- | ------- |——————-|  
Yes|    45    |    35   |  72   |
No |    27    |    37   |  0    |
```

Comment: Please post a code snippet of the database table - what you posted is not very clear.

Comment: Please provide the sample input of your table. You are talking about "count", but your expected result makes more the impression you need to "sum".

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT `key`, 
  sum(`french`) as french,
  sum(`spanish`) as spanish,
  sum(`english`) as english
FROM `answers` 
GROUP BY `key`;
```

```
key     french  spanish  english    
no      3       2        1
yes     1       2        3
```

Using the following schema

```sql
CREATE TABLE `answers` (
  `key` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `french` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `spanish` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `english` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `answers` (`key`, `french`, `spanish`, `english`) VALUES
('yes', 1, 2, 3),
('no', 3, 2, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your table that has the  three columns English, Spanish and French is called Source_Table, here's a query that does what you want:

```
select
  'YES' Key,
  (select count(1) from Source_Table where French='YES') French, 
  (select count(1) from Source_Table where Spanish='YES') Spanish,
  (select count(1) from Source_Table where English='YES') English
from Source_Table
Limit 1 
union 
  'NO' Key, 
  (select count(1) from Source_Table where French='NO') French,
  (select count(1) from Source_Table where Spanish='NO') Spanish,
  (select count(1) from Source_Table where English='NO') English
from Source_Table
Limit 1
```

Hope this helps.
Best regards.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to select from the Source_Table and limit this to one row. If you want to create one result row, then simply remove the `from Source_Table from Source_Table Limit 1` from your query. You are missing a `select`after `union` by the way. And you should not use `UNION [DISTINCT]` here, as there are no duplicates to remove. Just use `UNION ALL` instead, which just glues the two result rows without looking for duplicates to remove.

Comment: At last: `COUNT(1)` is something often seen, but it's a bit weird, because you literally tell the DBMS to generate a 1 per row and only count rows for which that 1 is not null. If you want to count rows, count rows: `COUNT(*)`. (What you are using is `COUNT( <expression> )` and unlike the mere `COUNT(*)` this is meant to count non-null occurences as just described.)

Answer (score 0):

It is rather uncommon to use a string column for 'yes' and 'no' instead of a boolean column in MySQL, but well, the query is almost the same here.

You want one result row for 'Yes' and one for 'No', but each row has a mix of yes and no values. So, you need a `UNION ALL` for the two result rows. The two queries you are unioning go throgh all rows and count the languages conditionally. In standard SQL we would use `COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE french = 'yes')` for this, in some DBMS that don't support the `FILTER` clause, we'd use `COUNT(CASE WHEN french = 'yes' THEN 1 END)` or `SUM(CASE WHEN french = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`, but in MySQL this gets even simpler, as true = 1 and false = 0 in MySQL, and we can use a mere `SUM(french = 'yes')`.

The complete query:

```
select
  'Yes' as yes_or_no,
  sum(french = 'yes') as french,
  sum(spanish = 'yes') as spanish,
  sum(english = 'yes') as english
from mytable
union all
select
  'No' as yes_or_no,
  sum(french = 'no') as french,
  sum(spanish = 'no') as spanish,
  sum(english = 'no') as english
from mytable;
```